# Open PDF in 'xchange PDF Viewer' from Outlook Plug-In 'harmon.ie'

Tags: pdf, outlook, add-in, outlook-addin, harmon.ie

When opening a PDF File from harmon.ie plug-in in Outlook (lying on SharePoint) the xchange PDF Client opens but not the file I double-clicked. With Adobe PDF Reader it works and the file opens, but not with PDF XChange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means your PDF reader does not work WebDAV. Register the below registry key then check again. Copy this in a .reg file and register it

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mainsoft\Prefs\AcrobatSPI]
@="false"

---- Jean

Comment: You probably did not register the right key. Use this key ftp://free:free@ftpus.mainsoft.com/AcrobatSPI.zip